# Fixing flickring old video

Tags: video, video-quality, filter

I have a bunch video that looks like it's flickering. The video started as Super8 (70s), was converted to VHS some years ago (90s?), and was recently converted to AVI. It looks something like this

Hover the mouse over the yellow area. Hidden because the flickering would probably drive you crazy.

> [image]

Are there any tools or filters to fix this semi automatically. I thought about trying to write something that extracts all the frames and tries to figure out what level they should be. That sounds like a big project but it got me wondering if this is already a solved problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Premiere Pro or similar video editing software and plugin Flicker Free from Digital Anarchy with one of the preset.

Result of plugin work

[image: Result of plugin work]

Settings of the plugin in my case

[image: Settings of the plugin in my case]

Also I know some other methods but they are poorer and harder.